# Why are TikZ page anchors misaligned, when I am using a manual voffset?

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop, cropmarks

I am trying to place some objects with the `TikZ` `remember picture,overlay` options and `current page` anchors. At the same time, I am using `crop` to create cutting marks. Unfortunately I cannot just use the option `center`, but have to manually defined my `\voffset` based on external requirements. As long, as I am using `center`, everything is fine, but when I manually set `\voffset` to another value, the `tikzpicture` is virtually shifted. Please have a look on the following code:

```
\documentclass[paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    Test\footnote{Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[red] ($(current page.south west) + (-1,-1)$) -- ++(2,2);
        \draw[red] ($(current page.south west) + (-1,1)$) -- ++(2,-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My expectation would be, that the red X is aligned with the black edge cross. However this is not the case, as you can see: [image]

When you delete the `\voffset` line and use `center` as a command, everything matches. Can you please tell me, what I can do to get the correct alignment or maybe, what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you do not use geometry, you may need to add `\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth` and `\pdfpageheight=\paperheight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (see also this open issue: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/294):

```
\documentclass[paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{\hoffset}{\dimexpr\pdfpageheight-\paperheight-\voffset}}
\makeatother

    Test\footnote{Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[red] ($(current page.south west) + (-1,-1)$) -- ++(2,2);
        \draw[red] ($(current page.south west) + (-1,1)$) -- ++(2,-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]